# Can I use the field title in a newform as a tooltip?

Tags: jquery, sputility

I have a NewForm to add an new item to a list. I like to have a meaningfull tooltip for eacht of the fields on that form. I know it can only be done by changing the title of the fields.

How do I address this?

```
SPUtility.GetSPField('Status')....
```

or maybe what I found in another question,

```
$(".ms-formfieldcontainer:has(input[id*=_Title_ctl00])").att‌​r("title", 
"ToolTip goes here");
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In a normal html form it's easy:
    `<input id="firstname" name="firstname" title="Please provide your firstname.">`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. In SharePoint it's not possible to change the tool tip because it's linked to the title of a field. There are workarounds but they are complex. I solved it by putting a small icon in front of each field and have a title in there that displays some help text.

Comment: could you please tell me as to how did you achieve this? @Marco